# `parse_peek': No value provided for option '--port' (Thor::MalformattedArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

i installed ruby by follow [this](https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-20-04/) instructions both ubuntu 18 and 20. I want to install [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) on ubuntu.

But when i run `rails server -p` i get below error. i tried many times fresh installs but same. I use aws EC2.

Any ideas would be very appreciated. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    30: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    29: from /home/ubuntu/toy_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    27: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    26: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    24: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    22: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    21: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    20: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    19: from /home/ubuntu/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    17: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    16: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    15: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    14: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    13: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    12: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    11: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    10: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
     9: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
     8: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
     7: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:388:in `dispatch'
     6: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:388:in `new'
     5: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:127:in `initialize'
     4: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:45:in `initialize'
     3: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:26:in `initialize'
     2: from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/base.rb:79:in `initialize'
     1: from 

/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb:100:in `parse'
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb:228:in `parse_peek': No value provided for option '--port' (Thor::MalformattedArgumentError)
```

Comment: Either do `rails server` (and let it select a port itself) or do `rails server -p 3000` (or whatever port number you want to listen on)

Comment: thanks. when i run rails server server starts. But when i go `curl http://myip:3000/ ` i get connection refused error. So i thougt this is related with above error.

Comment: Note; i can reach curl `http://0.0.0.0:3000/ `

Comment: Then you're on the wrong site. You don't have an application layer issue, you have a protocol layer issue.

Comment: How can i solve this :) Related with aws?

Comment: I can't tell you. There's a million things that it could be. But frankly, if you can reach it with `0.0.0.0:3000` then what's the issue?